# Build Meteor/React mobile app with OSX 10.10

Tags: meteor, mobile, osx-yosemite, xcode7.2

I use Windows and want to build a mobile app for both Android and IOS with Meteor and React. However, [the Meteor website says](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/running-on-mobile), "Currently, Meteor on Windows does not support mobile builds."

I want to buy a cheap Mac that can do the compiling, so I found a Mac for about $100 from 2009 running OSX 10.10.  I'm thinking I can install XCode 7.2.1 on OSX 10.10 and compile the apps.

I've never built an app, other than for the mobile app tutorials I've taken. Do you see any problems with this plan?

Comment: You guys like to down vote but you don't know the answer, apparently. I bought the Mac and will have the answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Currently, Meteor on Windows does not support mobile builds."

Actually. It is possible to build android versions in Windows too, but your directory structure should contain no spaces and keep directory names as short as possible e.g. put your project to c:\projects\myapp ot something like that.